# Would you provide a study routine for Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, self-learning

I've been working on Spivak's Calculus for the past few days and although I can manage to solve most problems, they take a lot of time. Some chapters have over 20 exercises and it can take several days to get through the whole list. Would anyone care to provide a list of recommended exercises for each chapter? I take it that this book has been used in several honours course in Calculus, therefore someone should have a related material.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow to his "Calculus on Manifolds"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am little skeptical that someone else's study or course routine will be optimally adapted to your needs.  But yes, I have used Spivak's text in an *Honors Calculus* course, and [this webpage](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/MATH2400F11.html) contains a list of problems I assigned week by week.

I feel compelled to add that there were also lectures and lots of office hours: each problem set includes more than one problem that very few students were able to answer without some assistance from each other and from me.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks.

Comment: The links on that page to the PDFs are broken.  Add a `alpha.` to the domain name for each and they work.